# Numbering Divs IDs

Tags: jquery, html

I put together a bit of code but got stuck as i  want to do something quite simple but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<script>
$('div.right').each(function(ii){
     html = $(this).html();
     $(this).html(ii + html);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the numbers that has been put out to be the Divs IDs.

Comment: you can't begin an element id with a number if I'm not mistaken; thus, you would have to do something like `this.id = "r" + ii;`

Comment: @Joseph you are mistaken in the context of HTML5 (note the HTML5 doctype).

Comment: @MattBall Ah! forgot about that change... I'm probably going to need reminded 50 times too before I remember. XD  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: to be more specific, i got a list of divs that need to get Ids (basicly every second div needs a different ID) so i can arrange them to left and right using css.

Comment: @strupp: that sounds like you need a `class`, not an `id`. Or just use `:nth-child(odd)`/`:nth-child(even)` CSS selectors, if you can forego IE<9 support.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sgPMY/7/ 



Got it to work :) thanks alot guys, actually learned something out of there.

Comment: I would still recommend against using purely numeric IDs even in HTML5. Quite apart from compatibility with older standards and browsers, they interact poorly with the generally-unwanted behaviours of treating `window` as an array-like of frames and dropping DOM elements into `window` as a Collection.

Comment: If you were trying to create a zebra-striped list or table, then *you are doing it wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

the `$.html` is the html content of the div. If you want to change the id, you will have to use `$.attr`.

```
$(this).attr('id',ii);
```

the `$.attr` stands for "attribute" so lets say you want to change the id attribute of the html element you will type in `$(element).attr('id', 'new id');`  If you would like to change lets say the class name it would be `$(element).attr('class', 'New class');`

Comment: `.prop()` should be used instead of `.attr()` with newer versions of jQuery.

Comment: why on earth don't we just use natural DOM? O_o you can just do `this.id = "myId";`

Comment: no you don't have to. What ever you put in the attr('id', ...) or prop('id',...) function it will be used as ID. It will add a new ID or change the old one.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/sgPMY/7/][1] 


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/sgPMY/7/

Got it to work :) thanks alot guys, actually learned something out of there.